# Get text inside a tag with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get some text that is inside a tag, I call it keyword. This is an example `[@sometext]`.

I am not able to get only the text. I am trying to use this, reading an HTML and I will define inside my HTML some keywords like `sometext` explained before, so I need to get `sometext` and not `[@sometext]` using regex. How can I do this ?

The current regex I am using is this one: `\[@\w+\]`.

That regex will get `[@sometext]` and not `sometext`. I tried nearly everything.

Thank you very much !

---

**EDIT**

The solution was to use `(?<=\[@)\w+(?=\])` because I am using `Matches` not `Match` method.

Comment: Use a positive lookbehind and lookahead, like `(?<=\[@)\w+(?=\])`

Comment: Don't parse html with Regex use proper Html parser. Show html and what you want to take from it and we can help

Comment: I didnt know about that, it is working now !! Can you explain a little more what is that ? Thank you !

Comment: @P0lT10n: You do not need lookarounds, just access the group value as is shown in the answer below. If you only have 1 capturing group (ie. 1 pair of unescaped parentheses), no need naming it.

Comment: You do not need lookarounds with `Matches`: `var res = Regex.Matches(str, @"\[@(\w+)\]").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Groups[1].Value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine your match for the content with a positive lookbehind for the `[@` and a positive lookahead for the closing `[`, like `(?<=\[@)\w+(?=\])`. The explanation (courtesy of RegexBuddy):

- Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)

  ```
  (?<=\[@)
  ```
- Match the character "[" literally

  `\[`
- Match the character "@" literally

  `@`
- Match a single character that is a "word character" (letters, digits, etc.)

  `\w+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)

  `(?=\])`

  - Match the character "]" literally «]»

Answer (score 2):

Please try something like this:

```
        string html = @"<html>[@sometext]</html>";
        var regex = new Regex(@"\[@(\w+)\]");
        var match = regex.Match(html);
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

The key point is to use Group. The zeroth group is the entire match, here we need to start with index 1.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Named groups, change your regex to

```
\[@(?<Name>\w+)\]
```

then you can use

```
match.Groups["Name"]
```

But whatever you do, you do need to wrap the item you are looking for in parenthesis to create the capture group